# Is there any game that can I make as a project of programming fundamentals in java under 500-1000 lines?

Tags: java, game-mechanics

I'll be having my semester project of programming fundamentals in java. I'm a complete beginner and don't have much ideas. Since I'm fond of game dev I am thinking of making any logical and text based game. I have learned elementary programming, selection statements, loops and arrays. Can I make game based on these topics only under 500 to 1000 lines?

Comment: I've linked this question to some past Q&A about simple games to get started with, which includes some text-based suggestions such as choose-your-own-adventure interactive fiction, Mastermind, guess-the-number, or hangman.

Comment: The Q&A principle of stackexchange is not a good fit for idea brainstorming questions like this. You might want to ask this on a more discussion-oriented website.